# SoapUI setting up API testing on multiple nodes

Tags: api, soapui

Pardon in advance if this is something easy, i am new to soapui.

I have 100 different nodes IPs on which i wish to test different API commands. GET / POST requests mainly.

For Example, i want to create a test that connects to node (1-100) > gets response from node > uses the response as a parameters in next request > validates the data > continues to node 2.

Now i've been able to setup everything except for the "jump" between nodes. How do i configure in soapUI additional endpoints (from a file, not manually) and how do i tell the software to continue to the next endpoint ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SoapUI Pro you can use a DataSource Loop.

As DataSource you can use your file with the nodes IPs to map that to a property. As the REST request's endpoint you then simply type http://${DataSource#propertyName}. This will expand to the IP in your file. Don't forget to have a DataSource Loop step in the end to do the actual looping.

More information on how to use DataSources in SoapUI is found at http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/functional-tests.html